# What does the verb after なくちゃ or なくては mean?

Tags: verbs, conditionals

If なくちゃ is followed by another verb, is it read as "*you must do X **or else** Y will happen*" or "*you must do X **and then** Y will happen*"?

**Example:**
In this sentence (from よだかの星):
おまえは、曇ってうすぐらい日か、夜でなくちゃ、出て来ない。

**Is it:**  "As for you, it must be a dim cloudy day or night... or else you won't come out."

**Or:** "As for you, it must be a dim cloudy day or night so that you won't come out."

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize, but phonologically (in terms of sound), the ちゃ ending is a contraction of ては, and semantically (in terms of meaning), this ending does not mean "must".  The "must" meaning only arises by combining this なくては ending with a similarly negative verb like ならない or いけない.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are thinking of `なくちゃ` as `must`, but it's really just a contraction of `なくては`. `なくてはならない` and `なくてはいけない` are used to mean "must", and sometimes the final verb is dropped and  `なくちゃ` by itself is  used as a very casual way to imply that something must be done.

However, especially in cases where something comes after the `なくちゃ`, it can just mean `なくては`. See Jisho's definition [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83), and also a related question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25567/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83-is-the-short-informal-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93-but-why-is-there-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE-rather-than-%E3%81%AA).

In short, it's

> As for you, it must be a dim cloudy day or night or else you won't come out.

Edit:  Also see Eiríkr Útlendi's comment.

Comment: I knew it was a contraction, but I didn't know it also had an independant meaning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: なくては means "unless". You can simply interpret it as "You won't come out unless it's a dim cloudy day or night" instead of adding a verb and taking it as "must".

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers aren't wrong, but I think the question hasn't been fully answered yet.

なくては usually means "without" in a broad sense. Its meaning is actually more neutral than the "unless" translation that user4092 mentioned, and is often a hypothetical condition. Example:

辞書がなくては分からない.

It's important to distinguish also between -ては and -て:

- 分からなくては心配です "Without understanding (i.e. unless I've understood), it's a worry"
- 分からなくて心配です "I'm worried about my not understanding"

In the second example, 分からない is an actuality, not just hypothetical like in the first example.

> What does the verb after なくちゃ or なくては mean?

More generally, なくては means something like "[something] not being [the case] (at least), what follows will/did occur/is true/is my assertion." This is actually a very broad pattern: gerund + は. See chapter 22B of JSL (which I lifted the above examples from).

You can also follow with an adjectival, or any other predicate:　直さなくては危ないよ！

Even これじゃありません is an instance of this pattern (the gerund being で, where では is contracted to じゃ): this being the case/thing under consideration, it isn't that -> "as for this, it's not" -> "it's not this at least" -> "(it's) not this".

Also, as alternates for "must" there are patterns with  と and with the provisional, which are beyond the scope of this question. See [What is と in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/what-is-%E3%81%A8-in-this-sentence/25714#25714)
and [Difference between ~なきゃ and ~なくちゃ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/difference-between-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8D%E3%82%83-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83/4216#4216)